# Incorrect rep in topbar

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

I noticed that the topbar does not display the correct rep.

It misses 2 recent upvotes but the rep page shows them. Even after more than 20 minutes and reloading the page it is still incorrect. Normally it updates instantly.

[image: rep]

<sub>It is now correct again, but I received a lot of rep in the meantime that may have triggered that correction.</sub>

Comment: Blame caching...

Comment: Not this time - it is over an hour now. Still the same

Comment: Well, it did take caching 2.5 ***months*** to update my Area 51 rep flair...

Comment: Area51 is a totally different code base.

Comment: Try refreshing without cache. (ctrl+F5)